# RuntimeError: Expected hidden size (2, 24, 50), got (2, 30, 50)

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I am trying to build a model for learning assigned scores (real numbers) to some sentences in a data set. I use RNNs (in PyTorch) for this purpose.
I have defined a model:

```
class RNNModel1(nn.Module):

    def forward(self, input ,hidden_0):

        embedded = self.embedding(input)
        output, hidden = self.rnn(embedded, hidden_0)
        output=self.linear(hidden)
        return output , hidden
```

Train function is as:

```
def train(model,optimizer,criterion,BATCH_SIZE,train_loader,clip):
    model.train(True)
    total_loss = 0
    hidden = model._init_hidden(BATCH_SIZE)

    for i, (batch_of_data, batch_of_labels) in enumerate(train_loader, 1):
        hidden=hidden.detach()
        model.zero_grad()
        output,hidden= model(batch_of_data,hidden)
        loss = criterion(output, sorted_batch_target_scores)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(model.parameters(), clip)
        optimizer.step()
    return total_loss/len(train_loader.dataset)
```

when I run the code I receive this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected hidden size (2, 24, 50), got (2, 30, 50)

Batch size=30, Hidden size=50, Number of Layers=1, Bidirectional=True.

I receive that error in the last batch of data.
I checked the description of RNNs in PyTorch to solve this problem. RNNs in PyTorch have two input arguments and two output arguments. The input arguments are *input* and *h_0*. *h_0* is a tensor includes initial hidden state for each element in batch of size(num_layers*num_directions, batch, hidden size).
The output arguments are *output* ans *h_n*. *h_n* is a tensor includes hidden state for t=seq_len of size (num_layers*num_directions, batch, hidden size).

in all batches (except the last batch) the size of h_0 and h_n is the same. but in the last batch, perhaps number of elements is less than batch size. Thesefore the size of h_n is (num_layers*num_directions, remained_elements_in_last_batch, hidden size) but the size of h_0 is still (num_layers*num_directions, batch_size, hidden size).

So I receive that error in the last batch of data.

How can I solve this problem and handle the situation in which the size of h_0 and h_n is different?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the last batch? You can just ignore it. You can also pad it. Or you can change your RNN to work with different sizes.

Comment: Very good suggestions. I should check if ignoring the last batch doesn't affect so much on the performance. How can I change RNN to work with different sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens when the number of samples in data set is not a multiple of the size of the batch. Ignoring the last batch can solve the problem. For identifying the last batch, check the number of elements in each batch. If that was less than BATCH_SIZE then it is the last batch in data set.

```
if(len(batch_of_data)==BATCH_SIZE):
    output,hidden= model(batch_of_data,hidden)
```